# The way to unescape escaped regex pattern Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to unescape the escaped regex pattern to apply it to a string.
It's actually dynamic I don't exactly know what it would look like, but throughout my testing I encountered one problem, the string with escaped regex pattern looks like this:

```
\\d{4}
```

I've written a simple regex which replaces every single combination of backslash and a character [with just a character](https://regex101.com/r/VdHVtd/1)

And I'm applying it this way:

```
sub(r"\\(.)", "\\1", escaped_pattern)
```

But what it gives me afterwards is `d{4}` not `\d{4}` as I expect.

I've tried using raw strings for repl, escape\unescape it, it still doesnt return what I expect it to return. Would appreciate any help.

EDIT

```
escaped_pattern = settings.reg_exp
regexp = sub(r"\\(.)", "\\1", escaped_pattern)
search(regexp, string_to_regexp).group()[0]
```

Comment: Have you tried `r"\\\\(.)"`? Even within raw strings, you need to be careful with escape characters. Even if *python* doesn't treat backslashes in raw strings as escape characters, regex *does*. So you have to escape your backslashes even inside the raw string.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy just tried it. It returns unchanged escaped regex string which is `\\d{4}`

Comment: Do you have a more complete code example showing the context of these strings?

Comment: @PyPingu there is actually just one variable which is the escaped_pattern. I grab it from the settings where this string is obviously escaped before saving.

Comment: But what exactly is is that you need "\d{4}" for and what is the output you currently versus what you want? You mention "applying it to a string"

Comment: Please post a minimal complete code sample: somewhere you must be escaping the string, but it isn't clear from your question where that is.

Comment: @Duncan updated a question, that's literally what i do.
And  second line of the code just returns the exact same string that is currently in escaped_pattern

Comment: And what does `string_to_regexp` look like. And what is the current output of the `search` versus the desired output?

Comment: @PyPingu it doesnt matter, since right now the correct regexp could be applied because I cant unescape it

Comment: I'm not convinced you need to escape it to get what you want, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you update I'm pretty sure that you would get exactly your desired output if you just stopped trying to unescape it.

```
import re
s1 = "1234astring"
matches = re.search("\\d{4}", s1) 
matches.group(0)
"1234"
matches.group()[0]
"1"
```

Comment: So it means that I dont have to unescape the regex patterns at all or is it just a lucky case?

Comment: If you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)  you will see why this works and the situations in which it will work, because whether you have to "unescape" your regex pattern will depend on exactly what it is. Read more on python raw string literals too.

Comment: I feel like this leaves the unexpected behaviour of `re.sub` unexplained, which still bothers me. So far as I can tell this has to do with python's weird way of escaping, even in raw strings, but overall, I still don't understand why `re.sub` behaves this way, when other regex engines don't.

Comment: I guess it might be a little confusing, but it’s not unexpected in the sense that it’s returning what the documentation says it will

Answer (score 0):

Try `r"\\\\(.)"` in search pattern and `'\\\1'` in substitution pattern.
works OK here: https://regex101.com/r/M3ikqj/1

Comment: my example works there as well :) The thing is that python somehow messes it up

Comment: Tried it, still returns an unchanged escaped string